# Magento 2 which of the elements automatically render their children in layout Xml?

Tags: magento2.3, layout, blocks, render, child

Which two elements automatically render their children in Xml?

1. `<block class=”\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock” name=”shop.info.details”/>`
2. `<block class=”\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template” name=”shop.info.details”/>`
3. `<container name=”shop.info.details”/>`
4. `<block class=”\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text\ListText” name=”shop.info.details”/>`

Answer (score 1):

3 and 4 I’d say.

Abstract block will not work as its class cannot be instantiated.

Template is likely the most commonly used but it does not render its children unless the template dictates it